# Visual Basic- I've got an error

Tags: vb.net

It says error on Line 32....
The given code is of visual basic. I guess I have got everything correct but have no clue what I did wrong. when I checked about it in the console it said line 32

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim isInKG As Boolean = Nothing
        Dim canDrink As Boolean = Nothing
        Dim isSeniorCitizen As Boolean = Nothing
        Console.WriteLine("what is your age?")
        Dim age As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim outcomeKG As String = Nothing
        Dim outcomeSenior As String = Nothing
        Dim outcomeDrink As String = Nothing
        If age <> 5 Then
            isInKG = False
            outcomeKG = "You arent in KG"
        Else
            isInKG = True
            outcomeKG = "You are in KG"


        End If
        If age >= 65 Then
            isSeniorCitizen = True
            outcomeSenior = "You are a Senior Citizen"
        Else
            isSeniorCitizen = False
            outcomeSenior = "You are a Junior Citizen"
        End If
        If age >= 21 Then
            canDrink = True
            outcomeDrink = "Go and get drunk"
        Else
            canDrink = False
            outcomeDrink = "Sorry Kiddo Not until 21 "
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(outcomeDrink & "  " & outcomeKG & " " & outcomeSenior " " &)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third row from the bottom has wrong order...
try this

```
Console.WriteLine(outcomeDrink & "  " & outcomeKG & " " & outcomeSenior & " ")
```